# Mongoid: return distinct values for embedded_in objects that fit an options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have got two classes

```
class Claim
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :claim_fields
  belongs_to :user
  ...
end

class ClaimField
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :claim
  field :title
  field :value
  ...
end
```

I need to fetch all unique values for claim_fields with current title for my claim through db (not by Ruby - it is too slow for thousands of records)

I've already tryied this

```
user = User.find(...)
Claim.collection.distinct("claim_fields.value", {:user_id => user.id, "claim_fields.title" => some_title})
# that is the same as user.claims.find(...).distinct("claim_fields.value")
```

But it returns ALL claim_fields values, and I need it to return only values for claim_fields with title that I need.

**PS** looks that I need some MapReduce here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fundamental problem here is that MongoDB queries only return entire documents. You are filtering on `claim_fields.title`, but the system is returning all `Claim` documents that match.

You're doing a `distinct`, but MongoDB treats sub-objects and Documents differently. As a result, the `distinct` is probably not doing what you want it to.

There are two possible solutions here:

1. Pre-calculate via M/R. (*as you suggest*)
2. Break these out into two collections.

Regarding #2, there is no requirement for embedding objects as you have. Embedded should be done based on the queries you plan to perform most. So if this is a common query, then it's fair to make these separate documents.

Comment: The problem is that in the beginning there wasn't any needs of querying through embedded objects, but now we need it